# How does my primitive species make baby carriers?

Tags: creature-design, culture, humanoid, daily-life

The Maruvans (plant/flowerlike species) are a very primitive and use Stone Age level tools. They can make clothes out of tree bark but I’m trying to figure out how they would make a baby carrier at their level. They can’t make advance baby carriers because of limited technology and tools. I was thinking about something like this where they weave a baby carrier out of bark similar to this Chamacoco mother with her baby:

[image]

That’s all I can think of. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already specified my problem. It’s relatively simple to understand.

Comment: [Cradleboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradleboard). [Baby slings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_sling). [Swaddling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaddling) ($\leftarrow$ this was the European way). (Ah, and as far as I know in the classical Greco-Roman world they just did not have any kind of specialized baby carriers; when they needed to carry their babies, they cradled them in their arms, possibly wrapped in a blanket, but not always. But they mostly did not expect the babies to leave the home before they learned to walk.)

Comment: @AlexP Thank you for the suggestions! I find the way the Roman’s handling their babies to be very interesting. I’ll soon determine which method is the best for Maruvan babies.

Comment: Hey I was trying to censor the image so it can be included in the question. Which of the two boobs is the problem? Is the exposed one or the other one where the baby is chomping down?

Comment: Oh, it’s just the right boob exposed! I couldn’t censor it because I’m on a phone but thanks for doing it for me!

Comment: @sydw1 Cool, I have just removed the right boob.

Comment: Thank you! :D Haha I seen it! It’s awesome and funny! XD

Comment: Uh... Can we consider it as being [inclusive and respectful](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/conduct) if we think that women nipples cannot be accepted, especially in a history picture which is neither erotic or pornographic? I'm not arguing with you sydw or @Daron. But well, we've seen much worse topics including... "Romantical approaches" between [dragons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/174287/80336) and [how to date without misusing your passive superpower](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/184980/80336). I just don't see what's the line of conduct here...

Comment: @Tortliena I don't know what the code of conduct is either. It  doesn't make sense to me why one would black out one breast but not the other.  If it was my question I would have used the image unmodified. But we have a new user here and it is worth demonstrating the options if something makes them uncomfortable.

Comment: @sydw1 Did you notice, what you "already specified" was basically "here's a picture of exactly what I said I wanted. For no given reason, this doesn't fit the bill…"

Comment: Ok to answers everyone’s questions, I do respect peoples’ cultures and I have no problem with half or fully naked indigenous people but I thought the picture I wanted to post was going to be against the rule and my post was going to be removed or flagged. I don’t know the the rules so I wanted to be careful. I would love to post the picture without censorship but I had to be mindful of the mods and their rules too. I know nudity isn’t inherently sexual but unfortunately the West have oversexualized nudity. It’s a shame that this is a thing but westerners are very sensitive about nudity.

Comment: I don’t agree with censoring indigenous people because it’s a part of their culture. Westerns are fully clothed and aren’t used to nudity in a non-sexual way. I imagined my species as half or fully nude but I got scared because I thought it would be controversial but I don’t care anymore because there’s nothing bad about nudity. Nudity isn’t the problem, it’s people depicting nudity in a hypersexual way.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Well, it was an idea I was considering, I never said I wanted that’s how I exactly wanted. I apologize for the confusion, I was trying to tell the robot that I already specified my problem and provided details.

Comment: @Sydw1 Yes and I was trying to help the robot tell you why that didn't work.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Oh okay nvm then

Comment: @sydw1 Oh, OK and How is it not obvious that "NVM" would be up to the Bot, to me and to everyone else who's time you took… and last, if ever, to you. ?

Answer (score 6):

Most primitive people have cordage; basically ways to use plants to make cord, string, rope, etc. The word "linen" comes from the word "lin" which was the German word for the flax plant; this particular plant has quite strong fibers in the stem; the stems can be dried, crushed, and fairly long threads extracted, then woven or knotted together. Even by hand.

There is evidence of nets being made from plant sources many thousands of years ago, used for fishing or carrying cargo. (The plant-stuff rots away, but the pattern can be found in mud impressions of the net, that later fossilized into rocks.)

I'd assume your people can make nets, and a very natural way to carry a baby is, like your picture, a net or cloth carrier that can be worn over the shoulders, and tied around the waist. Not much different than the carriers you see today, for carrying infants on your chest or back.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the insight! Ancient people were much more skilled and advanced than we thought. So like you said, my peoples’ baby carrier wouldn’t be any different than ancient humans’.

Comment: And baby hammocks.   Easy rocking baby hammocks.  Baby nets could also be used to capture rogue babies.   Probably they will fall asleep when captured because the hammock will remind them it is that time.

Comment: Fun little fact: the root *lin-* for flax goes all way back; all *European* Indo-European languages have words for linen or flax derived from a variant of it: Latin *līnum* (from where French *linge* and *lingerie*), Greek *línon*, Russian *lyon*. But the problem is that the old languages don't agree on whether the *i* is short or long, which probably means that the word is not Proto-Indo-European at all, but rather adopted from some even older Old European substrate language which the Indo-Europeans found here when they came.

Comment: @AlexP That is cool; I never connected lin- and lingerie before. Cool.

Comment: @Willk Oh yeah! I never heard of baby hammocks, that’s a nice little invention! I have to check that out.

Answer (score 3):

## Grow It:

These are plant people, right? Perhaps they grow a structure when they are having a baby, and then the parent that grows the structure has it growing off of them'

## Wicker:

You don't need a ton of tech to weave baskets, and it would be a similar task to weave a baby carrier out of sticks, or reeds, or leather.

## Fur:

Just because your people are plants doesn't mean they don't hunt. Lots of baby carriers are made of cloth, leather, or simply a hide cut to the right size and tied around the neck or shoulders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are good materials to use to make baby carriers!

Answer (score 2):

## Wicker Papoose

[image: Wicker]

How is babby carried? In a wicker papoose of course. Wicker is made of woven grass or reeds. Similar to textiles but with larger fibres.

The softness of the wicker depends on how dry the weaving material is. Using less dry material can make a soft bag or papoose to carry babby.

Plus eventually the papoose dries up and becomes rigid. Then you can store shells or seeds or whatever.

Comment: A wicker papoose sounds like a an excellent idea! I can imagine Maruvan mothers carrying their babies with wicker papooses. I think wicker baskets might be a neat concept as well.

Comment: Just for the record, "papoose" is considered offensive among many First Nations.

Comment: @KeithMorrison The only places I have seen the word are (a) to refer to a sling to carry a baby on the back or front and (b) in the original Peter Pan. Enough said about the second one being offensive or not.